# Covariant derivative - different notations

Tags: tensors

When one says that the correct action of the covariant derivative, say, on a vector $A=A^a e_a$, for a coordinate basis $e_a=\partial_a$, is :
$$
\nabla_bA\equiv \nabla_{b}\left(A^a e_a\right)=\left(\nabla_bA^a\right)e_a+A^a\nabla_be_a
=\left(\partial_bA^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}A^c\right)e_a \quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
where 
$$
\nabla_bA^a=\partial_bA^a\quad\quad\quad(2)
$$
and the definition of connection
$$
\nabla_a\vec{e_b}=\Gamma^c_{ab}\vec{e_c}\quad\quad\quad(3)
$$
have been used,

**Firstly**, It seems there is ($equation (2)$) the action of covariant derivative on the component $a$ of vector $A$ (denoted $A^{a}$) : this corresponds to the term $\nabla_bA^a=\partial_b A^a$

I would have thought that definition of covariant derivative should include intrinsically the term with connection (i.e $\Gamma^a_{bc}A^c$).

I thought that definition was :

$\nabla_b(A^a)=\partial_bA^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}A^c$

But why does one write : $\nabla_bA^a=\nabla_b(A^a)=\partial_bA^a$ ??

or maybe : $\nabla_bA^a \neq \nabla_b(A^a)$

**Secondly**, in the second term of Leibniz derivative formula ($equation (3)$), i.e the expression $A^a\nabla_b e_a$, the covariant derivative acts on a basis vector ( $\nabla_ae_b=\Gamma^c_{ab}e_c$ ) : we are here in the opposite situation where $\nabla_a e_b$ is equal to the second term of covariant derivative (I mean involving Christoffel symbols) and the partial derivative of basis vector $e_{b}$ components is vanishing.

For example, If I take polar coordinates for $a$ index (let say $a=\rho$ and $\theta$ for $b$ index , I could write :

$\vec{e_\theta} = -\sin(\theta) \vec{e_x} + \cos(\theta) \vec{e_y}$ and then :

$$\nabla_ae_b=\nabla_\rho \vec{e_\theta}=\partial_\rho (-\sin(\theta) \vec{e_x} + \cos(\theta) \vec{e_y})+\Gamma^c_{\theta\rho}\vec{e_c}=\Gamma^c_{\theta\rho}\vec{e_c}$$

since $\partial_\rho (-\sin(\theta) \vec{e_x} + \cos(\theta) \vec{e_y})=\vec{0}$ with $(\vec{e_x},\vec{e_y})$ the 2D cartesian basis vectors.

Finally, there is no difference between the two notations :

$$\nabla_bA\equiv \nabla_{b}\left(A^a e_a\right)$$

and $$\nabla_b A =\left(\nabla_{b}\left(A^a\right)\right) e_a$$

, isn't there ?

feel free to ask me further informations if these explanations are not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $$\partial_bA^a=\nabla_b A^a \not =\partial_bA^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}A^c$$
$$(\partial_bA^a+\Gamma^a_{bc}A^c)(e_a) + \sum_{k\not =a} \Gamma^k_{bc}A^c(e_k) = \nabla_b (A^a (e_a))$$
Here, $A^a (e_a)$ denotes a single scalar $A^a$ times a single covariant $e_a$ (i.e not summation)

The difference is that $A^a$ is a scalar, a rank-$0$ tensor, while $A^a(e^a)$ is a rank-$1$ tensor.

Second, $$\nabla_b A \not=\left(\nabla_{b}\left(A^a\right)\right) e_a$$

Comment: Can I write then : $\nabla_b(A^{a} \vec{e_{a}})=\nabla_{b} \vec{A}$ ? When you talk about $A^{a}e_{a}$, you want to say that $A = A^{a} (e_{a})$ is a vector of components $A^{a}$ in basis vectors ${e_{a}}$ : so a vector is a rank-1 tensor. In your answser, do you consider the basis vectors $\{e^{a}=dx^{a}\}$ and dual basis $\{X_{a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{a}}\}$ ? Finally, you say that $A^{a}(e_{a})$ is a rank-1 tensor, so this is assimilated to a vector : $A = A^{a}e_{a}$ with $A$ the vector ?

Comment: Syuizen: you mean that parenthesis in $A^a(e^a)$ expression prevents the summation ? Is this the same thing for $\nabla_{b}\left(A^a\right)(e_a)$ which is the covariant derivative of component $A^{a}$ in terms of $b\equiv \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^b}$, all of this times by vector $e_a$ ?

Comment: :Syuizen you say : " The difference is that $A^{a}$ is a scalar, a rank-0 tensor " . I don't think so because $A^{a}$ are the contravariant components of the vector $A$, so $A^{a}$ is a rank-1 tensor, isn't it ?